# How to get data in AudioBuffer based on time in seconds?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I know how to ***decodeAudioData*** from ***AudioContext***.
What i do not know is how to process the returned ***AudioBuffer*** from ***decodeAudioData***.

Let's assume we have some returned ***AudioBuffer***

```
{
    length: 12012146, 
    duration: 250.25304166666666, 
    sampleRate: 48000, 
    numberOfChannels: 2
}
```

Now i can ***getChannelData()*** from ***AudioBuffer*** which gives me an array about the length of ***AudioBuffer.length***.
I know the **duration** in **AudioBuffer** is `AudioBuffer.length / AudioBuffer.sampleRate`.

What i would want is to create a function which expects a **time** variable (in seconds) and then returns the data from the ***AudioBuffer.getChannelData()*** based on that variable.
So i would call `getChannelDataFromTime(seconds)` and it would return me an array of (for me) unknown size.

Am I missing something that would make my work easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you are looking for does already exist. It's at least a very similar function. It's called [`copyFromChannel()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer/copyFromChannel). It will copy a portion of the channel data into the given `Float32Array`.

Let's say you want to copy the channel data of the first second. In that case you need to create a `Float32Array` first which can hold the samples for one second.

```
const seconds = 1;
const channelData = new Float32Array(Math.round(audioBuffer.sampleRate * seconds));
```

Next you can copy the data into that `Float32Array`.

```
audioBuffer.copyFromChannel(channelData, 0, 0);
```

The first numeric parameter defines the channel to copy the data from and the second numeric parameter is defining the offset in samples.

Comment: Ohhh, now i see. Just one more question, what if variable channelData will be an array of different length like 2048, does copyFromChannel transform that data to fit the size of an array?

Comment: The spec for the function is here: https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-audiobuffer-copyfromchannel. It does not transform the data. It copies as much as fits into the given array.